# TMC connection error; SSD1306

Tags: marlin, ramps-1.6

I have some trouble with my small I2S OLED SSD1306. When enabled in Marlin 2.0.1 it shows up great *buuuut* with a bottom line saying TMC CONNECTION ERROR. `M122`  in pronterface shows:

```
Driver registers:
        X   0xC0:0C:00:00
        Y   0xC0:0C:00:00
        Z   0xC0:0C:00:00
        E   0x00:00:00:00    Bad response!
Testing X connection... OK
Testing Y connection... OK
Testing Z connection... OK
Testing E connection... Error: All LOW
```

Disabling ssd1306 in **configuration.h**:

```
//#define U8GLIB_SSD1306
```

and everything works fine.
I'm using TMC2209 for all 4 stepper on a RAMPS 1.6PLUS with a Re-Arm clone on.